# increase the size of text on Upload.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, master-page, file-upload

Is there a possibility i can ammend some CSS or something to increase the text size on Upload.aspx? I guess not but it would be very nice if i could.

Any advice would be great, we are using SharePoint Online 365 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a possibility, however, this way will change the upload forms all over your Site Collection.

You can add following Code to your masterpage:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
if (window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('/_layouts/15/upload.aspx') > 0) 
 {
  $("#element").css("font-size", "20px");
 }
});  
</script>
```

Mind to change the selector ( `#element` ) to the DOM-Element, which should be changed (You can find it via the Hover-Tool using Webbrowser-Dev-Tools).

Example: You want to change the font-size of "Datei auswählen":

[image]

Then the correct selector is:

```
$("span#UploadDescription").css("font-size", "20px");
```

Comment: brilliant, thank you very much.. but what Masterpage do i need to ammend ? I am on Sharepoint Online - just the normal one for the site collection ?

Comment: Yes - and here you can see the disadvantage :) The upload.aspx will be changed for the complete Site Collection and not only a specific one.